# R version of xtitsa

Tags: r, stata

I am currently trying to run an Interrupted time series analysis with a control comparison for my treatment group. I essentially want what the `xtitsa` package does in Stata but in R. I feel that I've searched everywhere and can't find it.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Up front, asking questions to recommend a package is expressly [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you might find some apathy or close-votes from that. Having said that, one trick for researching for packages/functions for R is to include either `"r"` or `"cran"` (quotes required) in searches. A quick google for [`"cran" "interrupted" "time" "series"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cran%22+%22interrupted%22+%22time%22+%22series%22) (quotes required), and the [`its.analysis`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/its.analysis/index.html) package supports the concept.

Comment: Thanks for the help and patience with a new user.

Comment: @r2evans is right on all fronts. Although their comment was very helpful, this is still off-topic.